# Using Quotes & Variable simultaneously in FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

My code is simply this

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim X As Variant
X = "3.7"
Range("O36").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({""C9:C34"",""F9:F34""}),"">=""" & Chr(34) & X & Chr(34) & "))"
MSGBOX "Total " & Range("O36").Value & " elements Standard Volts are Greater or Equal to " & X & " Volts"
End Sub
```

I have tried various combinations of `"" &` but to no avail. The output of the above code is

> =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C9:C34","F9:F34"}),">=""3.7"))

but of coarse it will  work only if it was

> =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C9:C34","F9:F34"}),">=3.7"))

Comment: Get rid of the chr(34) before X

Comment: Or change "">=""" to "">="

Answer (score 0):

To properly and simply write this type of strings, do as following:

1) Write the string in the way you want it to be at the end, for instance:

```
   Range("O36").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C9:C34","F9:F34"}),">=3.7"))"
```

2) Every appearance of a `"` between the starting and ending ones simple make it double, like this:

```
   Range("O36").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({""C9:C34"",""F9:F34""}),"">=3.7""))"
```

That's it!!!!

Comment: But there seems to be a wish from the op not to hard code 3.7 and use a variable's value there.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the idea is to demonstrate how to properly handle double-quotes within a string delimited by double-quotes. And yes, I am assuming that the OP will know how to use a variable in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier with a more direct approach (pun intended):

```
Range("O36").Formula = Replace("=SUMPRODUCT((C9:C34>=?)+(F9:F34>=?))", "?", X)
```

or maybe

```
Range("O36").ArrayFormula = Replace("=SUM((C9:C34>=?)+(F9:F34>=?))", "?", X)
```

You can also get the result without using range:

```
result = Evaluate(Replace("SUMPRODUCT((C9:C34>=?)+(F9:F34>=?))", "?", X))
```